# Change cartesian coordinates to polar via matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems

Change of cartesian to polar is well known, if one deals with a single vector at the time.

But what if a physics problem requires you to use several position vectors simultaneously.

Let A be a 6X6 matrix, and Vi and Vf be initial and final position vectors defined as

(x1  x2 x3 y1 y2 y3), where (x1,y1) represents position of particle 1, and so on.

Transforming (x1,y1) to polar at the beginning leads to a messy matrix A. 
On the contrary, solving the problem in cartesian coordinates (with x  coordinates in first block, and y coordinates in last block) allows use of symmetry to greatly simplify calculations. However, I fail to find a way to transform final result back to polar coordinates.

Any hints accepted :-)

Comment: Not sure why you can just use $x^i=\Lambda^i_jx^j$ for each vector?

Comment: Kyle: tried this approach, but was NOT able to find the correct lambdas. That is why I asked for help.

Comment: $\Lambda=\partial x'/\partial x$ didn't work?

Comment: Tried using cosine and sine directly. Accept I did NOT travel that road. Thanks